# program crashes on SwitchToThread() function because program detects wrong cpu info

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, jobs

I am trying to troubleshoot a multi-threaded program that keeps crashing.

I have pinned the error down to this function:
SwitchToThread();

which is part of the WINAPI

I have read some documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686352(v=vs.85).aspx

But it doesn't shed much light for me. And my understanding of practical multi-threading programming is limited.

It appears that SwitchToThread() tries to get the main processor to share it's load with the other processors.

I've put print functions before and after and this is the output I get right before it crashes:

```
Before SwitchToThread
After SwitchToThread
Before SwitchToThread
After SwitchToThread
Before SwitchToThread
After SwitchToThread
Before SwitchToThread
After SwitchToThread
Before SwitchToThread
After SwitchToThread
Before SwitchToThread
After SwitchToThread
Before SwitchToThread
etc.
```

It crashes before it can print "After SwitchToThread" eventually - so I know this function is at least part of the problem. It seems that it can't transfer the load.

The function definition for SwitchToThread() in WinBase.h looks like this:

```
WINBASEAPI
BOOL
WINAPI
SwitchToThread(
    VOID
    );
```

Which I don't understand - it doesn't appear to do anything.

Any assistance or if you could point me to some more documentation for SwitchToThread() - it would be helpful.

Comment: According to MSDN: "If the maximum number of threads is already running, no additional associated thread can run until a running thread finishes. If a thread uses SwitchToThread to wait for one of the additional associated threads to accomplish some work, the process might deadlock."

Comment: @C_Plus_Plus_Programmer That appears to be what is happening.

Comment: Basically, you create so many threads that it waits to create another, by which point the program has crashed.

Comment: @C_Plus_Plus_Programmer I've been looking into that possibility.

Comment: I'm extremely doubtful that `SwitchToThread` is the cause of your crash. Post some actual code.

Comment: It does appear to be related to the number of threads it is trying to create.(too many it seems). I'm still trying to understand how it uses words like "core" and "thread" interchangeably sometimes and not other times. Already knowing that there is probably an external problem from SwitchToThread is extremely helpful.

Comment: @T.C. The program appears to think I have only 1 core when in actuality I have 8 (4 physical 8 logical). Still trying to pin down the problem more before I post code.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. I think I fixed it. The function to detect the number of cores was never called. I will post the solution for posterity once I am sure. Or if one of you want to post it for points - that is fine.

Comment: You could have saved yourself a lot of time by using a debugger to identify which thread was crashing and where.

Comment: @HarryJohnston It actually wasn't the number of threads that was the problem - it was the number of cores being detected(or rather not detected).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that; by the time your program runs, Windows already knows how many cores it has, you don't need to do anything to "detect" them.  Perhaps you mean that your code was using an uninitialized variable?  You would probably have been able to work that out more quickly using a debugger.

Comment: @HarryJohnston That is correct. A variable used by the program called something like numCores was not initialized with the number of cores.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Maybe you can recommend me a better debugger.

Comment: Presumably your build tools already include a debugger, what's wrong with that one?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Just out of curiosity - which one do you use?

Comment: I use Visual Studio, which has a debugger built into the IDE.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I am using Visual Studio Express Edition 2010 - Are there any limitations on the debugger for the express edition? There seems to be. Maybe I should buy the full version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have no evidence that `SwitchToThread` has anything to do with the problem, and it almost certainly does not. It's just a pre-emption point at which the scheduler changes from doing one thing to doing something else. Presumably, it's that something else that causes the problem.

Comment: I changed the title of my question to be more clear. SwitchToThread was not the cause of the problem - it was just the point at which the program crashed due to an error that was made somewhere else.

Comment: @Stepan1010: that's still not a good description of the problem.  SwitchToThread wasn't the point at which the program crashed; the program crash occurred somewhere else - specifically, at some part of the code that was using the uninitialized variable.  The fact that an unrelated thread was calling SwitchToThread at the same time is irrelevant.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Feel free to write a better description and I will accept it. Assuming this question isn't closed soon.

Comment: Thanks David - I think I understand what you mean now.